# Move only the first .txt file from a folder using c#

Tags: c#

Simple question,I know you can use `FileMove` to move a file from one path to another.My question is,how can you move from a folder full of any sort of files ( `.mp3` , `.txt` , `.avi`) **only the first** .txt file from folder 1 to folder 2?

Comment: What is your definition of "first"? Alphabetically?

Comment: What do you mean with "the first file"? Do you want to move the alphabetically first .txt file of a directory or do you want to move all .txt files of the directory? I do not fully understand the question, I'm sorry.

Comment: first alphabetically,sorry ,forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a wildcard to `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`:

```
string filename = Directory.EnumerateFiles("Your search folder here", "*.txt").Min();

if (filename != null)
{
    // ... Do something with filename
}
```

`Enumerable.Min()` will return the 'minimum' string in the sequence (i.e. the first in alphabetical order), or `null` if the sequence is empty.

This is efficient because when you pass a wildcard such as `*.txt` to `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` it calls a Windows API method that only returns '.txt' files.

Comment: Does `EnumerateFiles` return the files sorted in an alphabetical order?

Comment: @mxscho Nope. I just noticed that the OP has changed his specification... Sigh.

Comment: You can just add a sorting step after `EnumerateFiles` and still have the best solution I guess.

Comment: Sure, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.GetAllFiles(@"path/to/files")
         .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
         .First(f => f.Extension == "txt");
```

This will explode if there are no files in the directory. It will also explode if there are no text files in the directory. This also depends on your definition of "First"

Answer (score 2):

You can use GetFiles

```
string[] files = System.IO.GetFiles(@"C:\users\youruser\documents\", *.txt);
if(files.GetLength(0) != 0)
{
    System.IO.File.Move(files[0],pathyouwanttomoveitto);
}
```